# How to make percentage of counts in Report Builder?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, builder

I'm using Report Builder to create a report.
I grouped data in MATRIX by column 'Names' and counted the number of occurencies (for some factor named Visits with 2 variables: Visit1 and Visit2).
Need to count percentage per row referring to the sum of column, e.g.:

```
Names   Visit1   Visit2  Total  Percentage
Adam      5         2       7       35% 
Mick      3         1       4       20%
Robert    1         1       2       10%
Anna      4         3       7       35%
Total                       20
```

I tried to do this in many ways but in vain. 
Expression which counts total is:

```
=Count(Fields!Visits.Value)
```

I added new column (to the right) and tried with diferent expressions but none of them works properly.

```
=Count(Fields!Visits.Value)/Sum(Count(Fields!Visits.Value))
=Count(Fields!Status_wyceny.Value)/Count(Fields!Status_wyceny.Value,"Visits_group")
=Count(Fields!Visits.Value)/Fields!Total.Value
```

In most cases I got '1' as a result:

```
Names   Visit1   Visit2  Total  Percentage
Adam      5         2       7       1 
Mick      3         1       4       1
Robert    1         1       2       1
Anna      4         3       7       1
Total                       20
```

How can I solve it I get correct result?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the SUM of the visits for each group by the SUM of all visits in the dataset.

```
=SUM(Fields!Visits.Value) / SUM(Fields!Visits.Value,"Dataset1")
```